# How to use gtalk/hangout on ubuntu terminal?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, command-line-interface, google-talk

I want to use gtalk/hangout on ubuntu terminal ? I dont want to use ui application for the same. Can anyone please help ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

I've started using hangups
https://github.com/tdryer/hangups

It's a google hangouts (not gtalk, but actual hangouts) terminal app written in python.

You can install it in Ubuntu with

```
#Ensure you have python pips installed
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install python-pip

pip3 install hangups
```

Comment: I had to install pip3 by `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` but worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

First, you could prove mcabber:

- It is a small XMPP (Jabber) console client.
- mcabber includes features such as SASL/SSL/TLS support, MUC (Multi-User Chat) support, history logging, command completion, OpenPGP encryption, OTR (Off-the-Record Messaging) support, dynamic modules and external action triggers.
- mcabber is released under the GNU GPL, and has been tested on GNU/Linux, BSD, Mac OS X and Cygwin.

If it is not that what you look for, then:

### First option

Not, if it is exactly what you look for, but it can serve to you as aid, I leave you like installing plugin in Ubuntu:

You can find in [the page](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/install-google-talk-ubuntu-official-repository/).

Next I also leave the information you:

"...
**(I have put h tttp but really it is HTTP, it changes it before using it)
To get started, press Ctrl+Alt+T to open terminal, then follow the steps below:

1.) Run this command to add the official repository:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb h ttp://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-talkplugin.list'
```

2.) Download and install the key:

```
wget -q -O - h ttps://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

3.) Update the package lists to make it available:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

4.) Finally install the plugin via Synaptic Package Manager, or by this command:

```
sudo apt-get install google-talkplugin
...
//Font: h ttp://ubuntuhandbook.org"
```

### Second option

Another way, to use gtalk/hangout in Ubuntu would be installing this plugin of chrome, in [the direction](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd?hl=en).

---

I hope that it serves to you as aid, a greeting, Pau.

Comment: I did not remember, also you can use: bitlbee.
Description from it web:
"BitlBee brings IM (instant messaging) to IRC clients. It's a great solution for people who have an IRC client running all the time and don't want to run an additional MSN/AIM/whatever client.
BitlBee currently supports the following IM networks/protocols: XMPP/Jabber (including Google Talk), MSN Messenger, Yahoo! Messenger, AIM and ICQ, and the Twitter microblogging network (plus all other Twitter API compatible services like identi.ca and status.net)."